# Java What this piece of codes means?

Tags: java

Can anyone please explain to me what this piece of code is trying to do and how it cycles through?

```
for(E a : this) <-------- This code right here.
```

Comment: It is called enhanced for loop. It lets you iterate over any `Iterable<E>` with `for (E element : somethingIterable<E>)` or arrays `Type[]` with `for (Type t : arrayOfType)` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: It is a "for each" loop in an instance method in an object of a class that implements `Iterable<E>`.

Comment: Another form of a for loop. We call it the for each loop. Probably the simplest way to iterate over an array or a list. Within the for each you could just do a[dot][number] to get a particular element in the list.